# Why am I getting "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'WarehouseBatchContentId'" When I am trying to get a WarehouseBatch?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I keep getting this error message even though the table I am trying to `GetById()` (a method from my generic repository) from doesn't have a `WarehouseBatchContentId` in it. I am trying to get the `WarehouseBatchId` which is in the `WarehouseBatch` table as opposed to the `WarehouseBatchContent` table which does have a `WarehouseBatchContentId` in it.

I can't see where this mix up has happened!

Product batcher application:

```
public class ProductBatcher : IBatchProducts
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;
    private readonly IGenericRepository<WarehouseBatchContent> _warehouseBatchContentRepo;
    private readonly IGenericRepository<WarehouseBatch> _warehouseBatchRepo;

    public ProductBatcher(IGenericRepository<WarehouseBatchContent> warehouseBatchContentRepo, IUnitOfWork uow, IGenericRepository<WarehouseBatch> warehouseBatch)
    {
        _warehouseBatchContentRepo = warehouseBatchContentRepo;
        _uow = uow;
        _warehouseBatchRepo = warehouseBatch;
    }

    /*creating a method which takes all the parameters and is called in the program.cs file*/
    public void BatchMover(int Id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dto);
        
        var oldBatch = _warehouseBatchRepo.GetById(Id);

        if (oldBatch == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("No batch matching the input");
        }
    }
}
```

`WarehouseBatchContent` domain:

```
namespace Domain;

public class WarehouseBatchContent
{
    protected WarehouseBatchContent()
    {
        WarehouseBatches = new List<WarehouseBatch>();
    }

    public WarehouseBatchContent(int warehouseBatchId, int manufactoringLotId, int quantity)
    {
        WarehouseBatchId = warehouseBatchId;
        ManufactoringLotId= manufactoringLotId;
        Quantity= quantity;
    }

    public int WarehouseBatchContentId { get; private set; }
    public int WarehouseBatchId { get; private set; }
    public int ManufactoringLotId { get; private set; }
    public int Quantity { get; private set; }

    public virtual ManufactoringLot? ManufactoringLotNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual WarehouseBatch? WarehouseBatchNavigation { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<WarehouseBatch> WarehouseBatches { get; protected set; }
}
```

`WarehouseBatch` domain:

```
namespace Domain;

public class WarehouseBatch
{
    public WarehouseBatch(int locationId)
    {
        LocationId = locationId;
    }

    public int WarehouseBatchId { get; private set; }
    public int LocationId { get; private set; }

    public virtual Location? LocationNavigation { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<WarehouseBatchContent> WarehouseBatchContents { get; set; } = new List<WarehouseBatchContent>();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

I was expecting the `GetById()` to use the `WarehouseBatchId` as the ID parameter, not `WarehouseBatchContentId`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: it was because of this line public virtual ICollection WarehouseBatchContents { get; set; } = new List(); which is not represntative of the one to many relationship in that domain

Answer (score 0):

```
[Key]
public int WarehouseBatchId { get; private set; }
```

try setting key from dataAnnotations library like this
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations